# How to redirect output from exe after it has terminated?

Tags: batch-file, redirect, command-line, dos

I'm trying to save the output of an exe file executed within a batch file to a text file. 
I've tried the the following methods but they don't work

This doesn't work since I'm back at the command prompt while the application runs and the text file created is blank.

`C:\>myexec.exe > mytext.txt`

`C:\>_`

`C:\>Status: Passed`

These also doesn't work. I get an empty text file and no output.

`C:\>start /wait myexec.exe > mytext.txt`

`C:\>call start /wait myexec.exe > mytext.txt`

This gives me an output at least:

```
C:\>start /wait myexec.exe
Status Passed
```

Comment: Which application is it?

Comment: It's a User Interface for NI TestStand called TestExec.exe which allows me to execute my automated TestStand test sequences from the command line. I'm trying to setup a Test Automation Framework and hence need to get the status back after the test has been executed.

Comment: Rather than reading text output, shouldn't you be testing for `ERRORLEVEL`? Most command-line apps use that instead because it's easily tested in batch files and allows easy automated use. `if %%ERRORLEVEL%% 1` is much better than comparing a file's content for specific text.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'll check for the ERRORLEVEL instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use /B operator.

This will cause the output to be redirected

start /B /wait myexec.exe > mytext.txt

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it like this:

**bat file content**

START /wait cmd /c "F:\MyInstaller\installer.exe > log.txt"

echo This will get logged after the previous is completed > log1.txt

Answer (score 0):

The `&` redirection operator duplicates output or input from one specified handle to another specified handle. For example, to send `dir` output to `File.txt` and send the error output to `File.txt`, type:

```
dir>c:\file.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `Application.exe >& file.txt`. This will output both, standard output and error stream, to your file.

Comment: I tried that but I still get the output on the console instead of the file. After the application has completed running, it does not redirect the output to the file.