# Redirect output of shell commands to file

Tags: shell, winapi, command-line, vb6, cmd

I am running following command from Command Prompt

```
dir > c:\log.txt 2>&1
```

The out is directed to `c:\log.txt` file successfully.
Then, running the same command using CreateProcessA as below and nothing happens

```
Public Function ExecCmd(cmdline$)
Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
Dim start As STARTUPINFO
Dim ret As Long

start.cb = Len(start)
start.dwFlags = 1
start.wShowWindow = 1
ret& = CreateProcessA(vbNullString, cmdline$, 0&, 0&, 1&, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, vbNullString, start, proc)
ret = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, INFINITE)
Call GetExitCodeProcess(proc.hProcess, ret&)
Call CloseHandle(proc.hThread)
Call CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
ExecCmd = ret&
End Function
```

Here `cmdline$` is passed as `dir > c:\log.txt 2>&1`

I have tried [Batch file - How to redirect output from exe after it has terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616837/batch-file-how-to-redirect-output-from-exe-after-it-has-terminated) and [Display & Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)

Please suggest what is wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the shell function? Here is an example of how to redirect the output:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ExecCmd "dir >c:\log.txt 2>&1"
End Sub

Private Sub ExecCmd(cmdline As String)
    Shell "cmd /c " & cmdline, vbHide
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it worked, but how to wait for the command to be finished?

Comment: It worked with the API as well by adding "cmd /c " before the command

Comment: Of course it did.  This has nothing to do with Shell(), it's about command line syntax in the command line shell (cmd.exe).