# Passing < or > to shell command?

Tags: shell, vb6

I have the maintenance of an old software written in VB6 that I have had to change from MSAccess to mySQL. The program works by calling external database utility programs which redirect data to and from files using the shell.

While trying to write the new database backup and recovery functions I got a terrible surprise. It seems the angle brackets do not work when sending a commandline through SHELL function (p.e.):

```
Shell ("""" & mySQLdumpLocation & """" --defaults-file="""" & confFileLocation & """" nameofthedatabase > """" & backuplocation & """")
```

This instruction opened a command line window where the mysqldump output could be seen but it did not create the backupfile. When copying the same instruction to a cmd window it worked perfectly.

I noticed after many hours looking for information that changing the ">" keyword to -r made the job.

Now I'm facing the same problem withe the recovery of the backup. In theory I need to use this:

```
Shell ("""" & mysqlexeLocation & """" --defaults-file="""" & confFileLocation & """" nameofthedatabase < """" & backuplocation & """")
```

...and no, it does not work. It does nothing. The same instruction copied to cmd window works as expected... and I haven't found a substitute for the "<".

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Could you make a batch file or PowerShell wrapper that does the job properly? Would be easier to call that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect output of shell commands to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717260/redirect-output-of-shell-commands-to-file)

Comment: Yes, the `>` comes from the shell .  `Shell()` runs the executable directly without the cmd.exe interpreter, so to get the functionality, you have to run it through `cmd.exe`.  Hence, `Shell("cmd /c """ & commandToRun & """")`.

Comment: Nop, sorry. Already tried all these options. Adding 'cmd' in the call makes the command line window open WITHOUT anything, adding cmd /c just 'open-close' the command line window without doing anything. :_(

Comment: Just as an off-the-cuff idea...  If nothing else works, you could likely... 1) get a temp file name 2) write the command you want, with ` > ` , into a `.bat` file, dynamically generated of course, with the output file you want, and, even put an `@echo off` at the beginning..  3)  Use `Shell(...)` on the `.bat` file.  Unless you're on *nix, then do bash.

Comment: Yes, finally it's the workaround I have used... but it still drives me crazy!! ... it's something 'personal' between me and vb6 ... I need to know how to kick his ass X_DDDD. Thank you guys.